# jquery: how do you loop through each newline of text typed inside a textarea?

Tags: jquery

lets say inside a `<textarea>`, i type in a bunch of keywords on each new line.

```
keyword1
keyword2
keyword3
...




$('textarea[name=sometextarea]').val().split('\n').each(function(e){
alert($(this));                 
});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The array object doesn't have any `each` method. As you are looping strings and not elements, use the `jQuery.each` method (instead of the jQuery().each method):

```
var lines = $('textarea[name=sometextarea]').val().split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(){
  alert(this);
});
```

Comment: this returns [Object object] and not the string.

i tried this.text(), and it says no method error.

Comment: its says this.text() is not a function.

Comment: @aoghq: jQuery casts the value to Object for some reason. You can use String(this) to get the value cast back to string.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is with the jquery object. val() returns a string and split() will return an Array. But each() is a property of the JQuery object. Try this instead:

```
$($('textarea[name=sometextarea]').val().split('\n')).each(function(e){
alert($(this));                                 
});
```

notice the extra $(...) around the the split() return.

Comment: The $().each() method is intended for iterating over elements, the $.each() method is recommended for iterating over other objects, like an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides an `each` method on the `jQuery` (or `$`) object. This should be used, rather than creating a jQuery object out of an array:

```
$.each($('textarea[name=sometextarea]').val().split('\n'), function(e){
    alert(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#your-text-area").live("keypress",function(){
            var lines = $(this).val().split("\n");
            $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
                     console.log(elem);
            $("<li></li>").text(elem).appendTo($("#target"));
});
```

You can "listen" using live on keypress, as the others suggested split by newline and the trick in the loop is that with "each" you get an index and value (elem in the code). This snippet appends the line value to another target element which you can empty before looping using 
    $("#target").empty();

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

```
$.each($('textarea[name=sometextarea]').val().split('\n'), function(e){
alert(this);                                 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this with codeigniter and php.
Here is a code:

```
$this->load->helper('text');
$name = 'some text that is longer than the width of text area and you need to do some thing with it...';
$name_array = word_wrap($name, 20); //20 is a number of character where your text will be wrapped.
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $name_array) as $line){
         echo $line.'</br>';
    //from here, you can do what ever you want with $line, put it to another array..whatever
}
```