# Wrap each element with html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="inner">
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inner').wrapInner('<p/>');
});
```

The current code adds the the `<p>` tag around all the elements, is it possible to add the `<p>` to each? like

```
<p>line 1</p>
<p>line 2</p>
<p>line 3</p>
```

Comment: How are the lines delineated?

Comment: its a list copied from a word document

Comment: `@Grundizer`: That doesn't answer the question. In the markup, what makes it clear that a line is a line? Remember that line breaks in HTML are just whitespace, not actual line breaks, except in `pre` elements.

Comment: You'll need to separate each line - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155678/javascript-string-newline-character and then wrap each one individually...

Comment: I'm trying to create a markup that isnt there...the data is given to me in word format there are no line breaks there

Comment: You need to Look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726747/jquery-how-do-you-loop-through-each-newline-of-text-typed-inside-a-textarea

Comment: Is your data coming dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go ahead :

http://jsbin.com/usuciq/edit#javascript,html

```
var g=$(".inner").html().split(/\n/);

var t= $.map (g,function (a){ if (a!='') return '<p>'+a+'</p>';});

$('.inner').html(t.join(''));
```